# Salesforce SFMC : FuelSDK Python - Unable to retrieve data from Shared Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, marketingcloudapi

We are trying to retrieve data from Shared data extension in Salesforce marketing cloud through FuelSDK Python.

Below is the code snippet:

```
import FuelSDK
import ET_Client
stubObj = FuelSDK.ET_Client(True, False,{'clientid': 'xxx','clientsecret':'xxx','useOAuth2Authentication': 'True',     'authenticationurl': 'https://abc.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/','applicationType': 'server','baseapiurl': 'https://abc.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/','soapendpoint': 'https://abc.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/'})
myDERow = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension_Row()
myDERow.auth_stub = stubObj
myDERow.CustomerKey='xxx'
myDERow.props=['ListID']
getResponse = myDERow.get()
```

The response is as follows:

```
Error: Invalid object name 'C1212121.Click_Report'.
```

Could anyone suggest a resolution for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Shared DE are 'owned' by the EID/Parent so you would need to make the call at that level or pass the clientid to change context

Comment: Thanks @EazyE, Its working with Parent MID access token